# How to remove a Work Account from Windows 11

Tags: user-accounts, windows-11

Im unable to remove old Work accounts from a PC , windows 11.
It is not possible to login to this account anymore.
There is no disconnect option and no remove option, except for the private account.
[image]

If you press manage it takes you to a company Office365/Azure page.
It is not possible to logon there.

I have cleared cookies.
Removed web credentials.
[image]
I checked that it is also not mentioned under Windows Credentials
[image]

I searched the registry for the user. It is not in the registry.

**How can all old AZURE/office365 account be removed?**

EDIT 2:
The solution is:

SETTINGS => Accounts => ACCESS work or School
NOT
SETTINGS => Accounts => Email and Accounts

That is a confusing design pattern.
Even after looking at docu, i didnt notice at first Id selected the wrong option.

Here is the correct screen:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of `Accounts -> Access work or school`?

Comment: It would helpful to know the contents of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments`

Comment: Rahmoud, that is the answer.   
Please move comment to answer.
There are 2 almost identical looking pages. I was on the wrong page and wasnt aware of the 2nd option. 
The option to disconnect is in one page and not in the other.
Going via EMAIL and ACCOUNTS the option to disconnect is not shown.
I did know they was a 2nd screen where it was offered to disconnect.

That is what I was looking for....

Comment: @Ramhound please write simple answer so I can mark as correct.
Issue was I was looking in the wrong place for the option and didnt realize there was a second option for Access control where the email/account is removed/disconnected.

Comment: I don’t have Windows 11 you should self-answer

Answer (score 2):

Type this into the run menu:

```
control userpasswords2
```

Select the user you want to delete and click "remove"

Comment: also works. thx. Up mark as it is a possible solution. Going to `Accounts-->Access Work or School` instead of `Accounts --> Email and Accounts` remains the "Best answer".
I'll give ramhound a chance to collect...